# Are shared memory initial values well-defined?

Tags: python, macos, shared-memory

The following code runs without error on macOS:

```
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=4)
for b in shm.buf:
  assert b == 0
shm.close()
shm.unlink()
```

This indicates that the shared memory segment is all binary zero.

However, what I want to know is whether this is well-defined behaviour across all platforms

Comment: It's better to consider the contents *indeterminate*, and always explicitly initialize it if you need to.

Comment: It's more about OS. In Windows `SharedMemory` relies on [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga)/[`OpenFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappinga) calls, in POSIX it calls [`shm_open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

Comment: @VsevolodTimchenko Thank you . I did search but obviously didn't use the right terms

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate:

[Why does python's SharedMemory seem to initialize arrays to zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992434/why-does-pythons-sharedmemory-seem-to-initialize-arrays-to-zeros)

*This is operating system dependent. Python doesn't initialize the memory - it just takes the virtual memory address offered by the operating system.*